# what is difference between insert value and insert values in mysql statement?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Please, tell me difference between below mysql statement:

> INSERT INTO `test` (first_name,last_name,age) 
>   **VALUE** (:i_first_name,:i_last_name,:i_age), (:i_first_name,:i_last_name,:i_age);

and

> INSERT INTO `test` (first_name,last_name,age) 
>   **VALUES** (:i_first_name,:i_last_name,:i_age), (:i_first_name,:i_last_name,:i_age);

Both are working fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no difference, as you can see from the syntax rules here, both keywords are valid: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 5):

It is more a readability issue, if the data you are going to insert contains **more than one** column use `VALUES`, otherwise use `VALUE`.

Comment: Maybe, visa versa?